# The syntax of concat in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, concatenation, reduce

```js
let items = ['Tom','Bill','Kim'];
let result = items.reduce((str, item) => str + '<'.concat(item).concat('>'),"");

console.log(result);
```

May I ask what the ending `""` does to the code?

Comment: That is the initial value for reduce function.

Comment: second argument for reduce (accumulator initial value)

Answer (score 5):

It's not related to `concat`, it's related to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It's the second argument to `reduce`, which sets the initial value of the accumulator. E.g., it "seeds" the accumulation, so it's often called the "seed value" or just "seed."

Without that argument, the first call to the callback would get the entries at indexes 0 and 1 as its first two arguments. *With* that argument, the first callback receives `""` as its first argument and the entry at index 0 as its second argument.

---

Side note:

It's probably worth noting that that use of `concat` probably isn't the best way to do what that callback is trying to do. The author of that code is mixing string concatenation via `+` with `concat`, which is a bit odd. I'd use one or the other, or a template literal:

Using `+`:

```js
let items = ['Tom','Bill','Kim'];
let result = items.reduce((str, item) => str + '<' + item + '>', "");

console.log(result);
```

Using `concat`:

```js
let items = ['Tom','Bill','Kim'];
let result = items.reduce((str, item) => str.concat('<', item, '>'), "");

console.log(result);
```

Using a template literal:

```js
let items = ['Tom','Bill','Kim'];
let result = items.reduce((str, item) => `${str}<${item}>`, "");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the second argument to `reduce` as the initial value for `accumulator`.

Understand this way - With a single example

```js
// Add all numbers in arr

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let sum = 0 // this is the initial value

for (let n of numbers)
  sum += n

console.log(sum)
```

```js
// Again add all numbers in arr using reduce

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let sum = 0
sum = numbers.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
   return accumulator + currentValue
}, sum)

/**
 * First round -  accu = 0, currVal = 1 => accu = 1
 * Second round - accu = 1, currVal = 2 => accu = 3
 * Third round - accu = 3, currVal = 3 => accu = 6
 * Fourth round - accu = 6, currVal = 4 => accu = 10
 * Returns accu = 10
*/

console.log(sum)

// Reduce takes a callback
// Accumulator will get the initial value using sum
// currentValue is the each iteration value
```

Internally `reduce` returns `accumulator + currentValue` and save it to `accumulator` each iterate.